# XSD : fail to compile custom type

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xsd-validation

I try to create an xsd schame for this xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Listelocataires xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="locataires.xsd">
    <NoImmeuble>221B</NoImmeuble>
        <etage n="1">
            <appartement cote="gauche">
                <nom>Watson</nom>
            </appartement>
            <appartement cote="droit">
                <nom>Holmes</nom>
                <telephone>020 7465 4321></telephone>
            </appartement>
        </etage>
        <etage n="0">
            <appartement cote="droit">
                <nom>Hudson</nom>
                <telephone>020 7465 4321></telephone>
            </appartement>
        </etage>
</Listelocataires>
```

I try to create an custom type for the validation of the telephone number, but it didn't accept my answer, here is my xsd schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Listelocataires">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="NoImmeuble" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element ref="etage" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="NoImmeuble" type="xsd:string" />

    <xsd:element name="etage">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="appartement" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="n" type="xsd:string" use="required" /> 
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="appartement">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="nom" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element ref="telephone" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="cote" type="xsd:string" /> 
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="nom" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:element name="telephone" type="typeTelephone"/>

    <xsd:simpleType name="typeTelephone">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="\d{3} \d{4} \d{4}" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

Xmllint give me those errors :

locataires.xml:10: element telephone: Schemas validity error : Element 'telephone': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'à020 7465 4321>' is not accepted by the pattern 'à\d{3} \d{4} \d{4}'.
locataires.xml:10: element telephone: Schemas validity error : Element 'telephone': 'à020 7465 4321>' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'typeTelephone'.
locataires.xml:16: element telephone: Schemas validity error : Element 'telephone': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'à020 7465 4321>' is not accepted by the pattern 'à\d{3} \d{4} \d{4}'.
locataires.xml:16: element telephone: Schemas validity error : Element 'telephone': 'à020 7465 4321>' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'typeTelephone'.

I don't understand why, if you see, please help me,
Best regards,
Zed13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for `telephone` does not permit the trailing `>` characters that you have in your data.

**To validate your XML successfully, change the following line from**

```
<telephone>020 7465 4321></telephone>
```

**to**

```
<telephone>020 7465 4321</telephone>
```

**And this one from**

```
<telephone>020 7465 4321></telephone>
```

**to**

```
<telephone>020 7465 4321</telephone>
```

**Or, change the XSD regex from**

```
        <xsd:pattern value="\d{3} \d{4} \d{4}" />
```

**to**

```
        <xsd:pattern value="\d{3} \d{4} \d{4}>" />
```